# HTML enclose text with no extra whitespace in div tag

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

**Disclaimer: I am decently new to HTML.** I know this is (most likely) going to be marked as a repeat, however i am not able to word it out and search so i am unable to find the information i need, so i came to ask this very simple question on stack overflow.
I have a quick HTML login form, with a div:
[image: HTML Form with extra space.]

In the image given above there is my login form aligned to the right, and there is a 2px black border surrounding it, is it possible to make the border only enclose the login form and not the extra whitespace in the left.

Result wanted:
[image: HTML Div tag (drawn figure)]

Thanks!
Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html body {
            margin:20px;
        }
        #login-form{
            padding:30px;
            border:2px solid black;
        }
        #title-login{
            font-family:Arial,sans-serif,serif;
            margin-right:235px;
            
        }
        .inpt{
            border-radius:3px;
            width:235px;
            height:30px;
            font-size:20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin:2px;
        }
        .userinpt{
            width:315px;
        }
        .passwdinpt{
            margin-right:83px;
        }
        
        .login-button{
            background-color: transparent;
            color: black;
            border: 1.5px solid #008CBA;
            padding: 13px 26px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius:5px;
            margin-right:210px;
        }
        .login-button:hover {
            background-color: #008CBA;
            color: white;
        }
        #ask-reg{
            font-family:sans-serif;
            font-weight:lighter;
            margin-right:10px;
        }
        #link-reg{
            
        }
        .link {
            color: #0099ff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .link:hover {
            color: #007acc;
            transition-duration: 100ms;
            transition-property: all;
            border-bottom: 1.3px solid black;
            padding: 0 0 0.8px;
            opacity:100%;
        }
        .link:active {
          color: #99d6ff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="right" id="login-form">
    <h1 id="title-login" >Login</h1>
    <form action="subindex.php" method="post" >
      <input type="text" class="inpt userinpt"  name="usrname" placeholder="Username or E-mail"><br>
      <input type="password" class="inpt passwdinpt" name="passwd" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
      <button type="sumbit" class="login-button" name="logn">Confirm</button><br>
    </form>
    <br>
    <p id="ask-reg" >If you do not have an account, register <a id="link-reg" class="link" href="register.html">here</a>.</p>
    </div>


<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the code snippet so we can see what you've done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `border` will always be surrounding the element `width` and `height` including the `padding`. change the `width` of the form and if you want it to align to the right use:

```
form {
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to set the `width` and `float:right` property on your #login-form element. Here's an example on repl.it: https://repl.it/@TrishaAguinaldo/example-border

Also, try not to use the `<br>` to break html elements. You can just set the margin/padding on an element for that.

[image]